# Rails country/state listings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in the process of creating an application with Rails, what I am trying to do is have each user, upon registration, select 1 country, and 1 state within the country they are associated with. I know I can create classes like Country, and State and use belongs_to, has_many associations. But how would I be able to list all countries/states in a form and how would I map together a specific country/state name to that one user?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can list them all with drop downs, and you would map them by saving their IDs attached to the specific user. This is a fairly basic part of Rails, so I recommend reading some help documentation. Consider Micheal Hartl's excellent book (great for beginners and advanced users). http://www.railstutorial.org/book

Answer (score -1, accepted):

grouped select, example specifies exactly what you need:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Carmen](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails).

No need to reinvent the wheel; it supplies the lists of countries and subregions so you don't have to manage them. The documentation also includes sample code for displaying the country-appropriate subregions (states) via JavaScript.

Comment: fwiw, I also use carmen and usually don't bother normalizing via database schema.